# typed.js not working on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, typed.js

I used typed.js for a text animation on this website : https://howareyoudoing.today/

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox. But on IE, it doesn't want to initialize and it's blocking my script. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably used `stringsElement: #yourdiv` which seems to cause the problem.
Try getting the strings by yourself using:

```
var myitems = [];
$('#yourdiv p').each(function (i, e) {
    myitems.push($(e).text());
});
```

And then use:

```
"strings: items"
```

instead.
Hope this helps